# Laravel Blade with Tailwind and Alpine: Tidiest way to make a multiple image file upload

Tags: javascript, laravel, tailwind-css, laravel-blade, alpine.js

After a lot of work, I've could properly find a way to make a multiple photo upload with just an only <input type="file" multiple...> within a form. I'm also obtaining a nice preview, in which I can slide through the images, and I'm able to delete some wanted photo by clicking a cross (X) icon located above the image.

I've based my code on the example provided by this article:
[Building a carousel component with TailwindCSS and Alpine.js](https://janowski.dev/articles/carousel-with-tailwind-and-alpine/)

The result I got was this one:
[image: preview]

And my code of my Blade view is this one:

```
<x-app-layout>
    <div id="handler" x-data="handler">
        
        <form action="{{ route('archivos')}}" method="POST" id="archivos" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            @csrf
            <input type="hidden" id="texto" name="texto" value="Texto de prueba"/>
            <input type="hidden" id="texto" name="texto" x-bind:value="foo"/>

            <input type="file" name="fotos[]" id="fotos"
                class="
                        w-full
                        text-sm text-gray-500
                        file:mr-4 file:py-2 file:px-4
                        file:rounded-full file:border-0
                        file:text-sm file:font-semibold
                        file:bg-blue-50 file:text-blue-700
                        hover:file:bg-blue-100" multiple />
            <button type="submit">
                Enviar archivos
            </button>
        </form>
        
        
        <template x-if="cargadas"><div>

            <div class="relative mx-auto mt-3 aspect-[2/1] w-3/4 flex items-center">

                <button class="relative left-0 px-2  w-8 h-8 group bg-gray-400 hover:bg-gray-500 hover:bg-opacity-75 cursor-pointer"
                
                @click="
                if(seleccionada==0)
                    seleccionada=sourcesImagen.length-1;
                else
                    seleccionada-=1;
                "
                >
                    <span class=" group-hover:block py-auto text-gray-50">
                        &larr;
                    </span>
                </button>   
                
                <img id="vista" class="aspect-auto w-3/4 mx-auto" 
                    :src="sourcesImagen[seleccionada]"
                    :alt="archivosImagen[seleccionada].name"
                    :title="archivosImagen[seleccionada].name"
                    />

                <button class="relative right-0 px-2  w-8 h-8 group bg-gray-400 hover:bg-gray-500 hover:bg-opacity-75 cursor-pointer" 

                @click="
                if(seleccionada==sourcesImagen.length-1)
                    seleccionada=0;
                else
                    seleccionada+=1;
                "
                >
                    <span class=" group-hover:block text-gray-50">
                        &rarr;
                    </span>
                </button>
                
            </div>
            <div class="relative mx-auto my-auto w-fit flex items-center">
                <button class="mx-auto h-5 w-5 text-2xl" x-on:click="eliminarFoto(seleccionada)">X</button>
            </div>

            <div class="relative mx-auto mt-4 w-1/2 flex items-center">
                <template x-for="(imagen,index) in sourcesImagen" :key="index">
                    
                    <button @click="seleccionada = index" :class="{'bg-gray-300': seleccionada == index, 'bg-gray-500': seleccionada != index}"
                        class="h-2 w-2 rounded-full mx-auto hover:bg-gray-300 ring-2 ring-gray-300"></button>
                    
                </template>
            </div>
            
        </div></template>
    </div>

    <script>
        let listaArchivos=false;
        let cargados=false;
        let list = new DataTransfer();

        const objeto={
            foo : 'bar',
            actFoo: function(){
                this.foo="Otro";
            },
            cargadas:false,
            eliminarFoto: function(index){
                if(this.cargadas){
                    this.sourcesImagen.splice(index,1);
                    list.items.remove(index);
                    listaArchivos=list.files;
                    this.archivosImagen=listaArchivos;
                    document.getElementById("fotos").files=this.archivosImagen;
                }
            }
        };
        
        const devolver = () => Alpine.reactive(objeto);
        
        document.addEventListener('alpine:init', async() => {
            Alpine.data('handler', devolver);
        });

        document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", async (event) => {


            function readURL(input) {
                if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
                    
                    if(!listaArchivos){
                        devolver().seleccionada=0;
                        devolver().cargadas=true;
                        devolver().archivosImagen=input.files;
                        devolver().sourcesImagen=[];
                    }

                    const offset=list.items.length;
                    
                    Array.from(input.files).forEach(function(file,index){
                        index+=offset;
                        list.items.add(file);
                        const reader = new FileReader();
                        
                        reader.onloadend = function (e) {
                            devolver().sourcesImagen[index]=e.target.result;
                        }
                        reader.readAsDataURL(file);
                    })

                    listaArchivos=list.files;
                    devolver().archivosImagen=listaArchivos;
                }
                return listaArchivos;
            }
            
            document.getElementById("fotos").addEventListener("change",async (event) => {
                readURL(event.target);
                event.target.files=listaArchivos;
                
            });
        });
    </script>

</x-app-layout>
```

Despite this works fine, I'm wondering if there's a better or tidier way to achieve the same result, since I found being such an ugly approach to be using all those global variables, at the beginning of my <script>, to achieve this result.

May anyone would suggest a better or tidier approach to achieve the same result?

I'm using Alpine v3